# ConstraintLayout - Size child to some percent of other child, not parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Say I have two views as children in a ConstraintLayout and want to layer the second one on top of the first one.
Additionally, the second one should have a size of some percentage of the other, for example 40% width and 60% height.
I also want it to position with some relative offset within the first view, say 20% in width and 30% in height.

Below is the code I would expect to do that.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The offset (bias) part works as expected - the secondView is offset some percentage relative to the firstView.
The size of the secondView however is relative to the size of the parent ContraintLayout, not relative to firstView.
The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams#constants) confirms that and says:

> MATCH_CONSTRAINT_PERCENT -- The dimension will be a percent of another widget (by default, the parent)

In my case, I want said "another widget" to be firstView, not the parent.
I have tried a lot of different settings, both on firstView and secondView - to no avail.
The documentation, and even the source code of ConstraintLayout (as far as I could understand) didn't help me with this either.

**How can I achieve this kind of relative sizing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to add another layout with same weight and height from the firstView and put sencondView in it.
This might not be the answer that you wanted but I am sure it works.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstView">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/secondView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! While that does indeed work, I would prefer not to nest ConstraintLayouts if possible.
I'll mark it as accepted in a few days if I find nothing better =)